# Correct way of filtering results with AJAX in any server language

Tags: jquery, ajax, filtering

I have a controller (with RoR, but let's assume I have some server listening for a request) that deals with the search of hotels.  The default search is **by city**, so given a city, the controller will look for all the hotels in that city.

Once that view is rendered, I have a form that lets you filter the results.  My question is:

How am I supposed to save the current state of the user preferences (filters and city) in order to send them to the controller action again?

So, let's say that the user clicks on **sort by price**, and via AJAX I want to fetch the hotels for a given city (chosen before) ordered by price. How do I know which city he has chosen before? Do I need to store it in a hidden field or what's the appropriate way of doing so?

Same question rises if after filtering the order by price, the user selects the luxury hotels option. I need to fetch hotels by a given city, ordered by price and with category of luxury.  Where am I supposed to store the prior states of the search?

Thanks

Comment: You're using AJAX so the page doesn't refresh and client-side state is preserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the prior states simply in a JavaScript variable or a hidden form field. Either is fine, and the right choice will depend more on your code design than on any kind of functionality/performance issue. And if you can't figure out which way is better for your particular case, don't worry about it because it probably just doesn't matter.

Comment: For me the choice is simple. With jQuery's `form.serialize()` available, there would need to be a strong case to do otherwise in all cases.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot If using form.serialize you are assuming that in my form there is the city, which is not. I assume I might have to put a hidden input field with the city in the filters form.

Comment: Hommer, yes that is implicit in my suggestion. That way, you only need one request mechanism - namely (in shorthand) `$.ajax({url:form.serialize(), ...});`. Presumably you currently have one mechanism for city and another for the filter. If you think of `city` as part of the filter, then the whole thing should simplify and the issue of how to remember `city` when applying the filter should disappear.

Comment: I'm sure Hommer knows what I meant but for anyone else I should have said `$.ajax({..., data:form.serialize(), ...});`

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Using serialize is nice. However if I have several checkbox with the same name, I just get the last value. I have tried to put value[] in the checkbox but still I don't get all the values. Any trick to do that with serialize?

Comment: None that I know of Hommer. There may be a jQuery plugin with a better form serializer. A quick search yields [this one](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) but I haven't looked too closely at what it does.

Answer (score 0):

You can send all the sorting options each time the user presses sortBy, so each time your controller gets the city and price your sql will look like "..WHERE city='city1' ORDER BY price ASC, anotherOption DESC" 
And to save the results per user: I think the best place is cookies. 
You can also sort the results by cookies only and change them only when getting smth. new from ajax call.